# apt-get install shows that inkscape is installed, but synaptics shows it isn't

Tags: apt, synaptic

This is mostly weird. I have a freshly installed Ubuntu machine, and I needed inkscape. I typed in terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install inkscape
```

and I get the message `inkscape is allready at the newest version.` However, when I tried to launch inkscape I was forwarded to synaptic. Is this an issue where inkscape is pre-installed and I only need to activate it?

Comment: I do not understand what you mean by "forwarded to Synaptic". Which Desktop environment are you using?

Comment: I'm using unity. When I hit super and type "inkscape" I see the inkscape logo, when I click it, synaptic opens and offers me to install the program

Comment: Sounds as if you are the new owner of your very own bug report =)